# How to start and stop a job on a particular day using Cron expression?

Tags: scheduled-job

I have to

- start my job on 26-03-2012
- stop on 26-03-2025
- it should run every day till 26-03-2025

I haven't used Cron expression before . Can you please help?

Comment: Is there a reason you are starting it in the past? Or is this just hypothetical I want to start on a specific day and end on a specific day?

Comment: @Peter Can you help on how to stop a job using Cron expression ? Requirement is not yet clear on the start part.

Comment: So @Vanilla_Sky this is the crux of my question so I can answer you better. Is it the start dat/time that is important, or it is that you want to end on a certain day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is pretty straightforward to understand. It is just a representation of a point in time and used in many different languages and technologies.

The Apex cron is explained in the [Apex language reference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm). There are components for second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week, and year.

Most cron implementations do not include a year component so in this regard, Apex is a bit special.

Cron is also good at ranges, and being specific within one range component, for instance, I want to run from 2015-2020. But if you put a second range in, for instance for the month to be January - March, I'm pretty sure it would always run in that range for all the years, there's not way to say, "only use this range for the last occurrence of year time component."

Hopefully this is making sense so far.

I think the way I would attempt to get this to work (and I confess this is untested, I'm just going by the docs) is to create several scheduled jobs. Take your example, I want to run (let's say from today) until 26 March, 2025. I would create three separate jobs (and for the hypothetical case, we'll have it run at 4:00 am for our once per day time):

- Run from now every day, until the end of 2024 at 04:00

  - `0 0 4 * * ? 2015-2024`
- For January and February of 2025, run every day at 04:00

  - `0 0 4 * JAN, FEB ? 2025`
- For 1-26 March 2025, run every day at 04:00

  - `0 0 4 1-26 MAR ? 2025`

The obvious down side: should you ever want to cancel this job, you need to make sure to cancel all three, or someone will be really confused/annoyed/angered come 2025.

But if you ask me (and I can't say this for certain), this clunkiness is more a limitation of cron, than the Apex scheduler itself. If you look at the Apex Scheduler in the UI, you can actually be more flexible as far as ending a single scheduled job on a very specific date.

[image: Scheduled job to end on 26 March, 2020]

Where the Apex scheduler user interface is more limiting is in running more than once per day, and (for whatever reason) the date picker for end date stops at 2020, so whoever created that UI didn't seem to want Admins to schedule code jobs to last more than about 5 years, or maybe thought the world would end by then anyway.